# Как найти и заменить класс?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Есть кнопка меню

```
`<div class="grid__menu">
   <i class="material-icons md-48 menu__button">dashboard</i>
 </div>`
```

при клике на которую, я хочу поменять класс `menu__button` на `menu__button--active`
Поменять класс можно и так

```
 var activeModificator = '--active';
 function toggle (className, active) {
     var name = className.replace(/\./g, '');
     var activeName = (active === undefined) ? activeModificator : active;
   if (name.indexOf(activeName) == -1) {       
      document.querySelector(className).classList.add(name+activeModificator);
      document.querySelector(className).classList.remove(name);    
   } else {      
document.querySelector(className).classList.add(name);
document.querySelector(className).classList.remove(name-activeModificator);
    } 
}
```

Но в функцию мне надо передать имя класса, которое надо взять из строки `<i class="material-icons md-48 menu__button">dashboard</i>`

Как мне получить имя класса из `document.querySelector(".menu__button");`? Там ведь сначала будет `menu__button`, а потом `menu__button--active`? И после первого изменения класс будет другой. Какой алгоритм вообще? Без jQuery

[Пример на jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TsarS/f0aqL0zk/1/)

Comment: "Там ведь сначала будет menu__button, а потом menu__button? "

Comment: Исправил, извините

Comment: обновил ответ..

Answer (score 1):

Решение типовое, **обновлено**

```js
document.querySelector('.grid__menu i').addEventListener('click', function() {
  classToggle('menu__button', '--active', this);
}, false)

function classToggle(a, b, elem) {
  console.log(elem);
  elem.classList.remove(a);
  elem.classList.add(a + b);
}
```

```css
.menu__button {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.menu__button--active {
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid__menu">
  <i class="material-icons md-48 menu__button">dashboard</i>
</div>
```

Comment: А если у меня не будет    <div class="grid__menu"> ? Можно как-нибудь из classList вытащить существующий сейчас?

Comment: И, кстати, этот код не меняет обратно при следующем нажатии. Т.е. не toggle выходит. В любом случае спасибо, конечно